# Update a simple database SQLite Android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

In my android application, I have 10 imageview and 10 buttons, initially all are having light color and when I touch a button, the imageview turns into a dark color.
In my SQLite I have 10 columns, every column with an Integer value, 0 for light and  1 for dark.

I'm a beginner in sqlite  Please tell me how to update tables in sqlite in detail , I've seen a few tutorial and I know how to create my tablet, what i really don't understand is how to update it.

Comment: Try to do some code and bring us your problems.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Comment: Read some tutorials about SQL CRUD operations on DBs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume you have an account object (account name, user, password etc) that you want to update. You also have a unique key (rowId). Then the update method could look like this:

```
public void updateAccount( AccountObject inAccountObj){

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COL_NAME, inAccountObj.getName() );
    values.put(COL_USER, inAccountObj.getUser() );
    values.put(COL_PW, inAccountObj.getPassword() );
    values.put(COL_NOTES, inAccountObj.getNotes() );

    String whereClause = KEY_ROWID + " = ? ";
    String[] whereArgs = new String[] { inAccountObj.getRowId().toString() };

    mDb.update(TABLE_ACCOUNT, values, whereClause, whereArgs);

}
```

To sum up: you handover the data to content values and the update the row in the database table using the unique key.

Answer (score 0):

This says - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_update_query.htm

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2...., columnN = valueN
WHERE [condition];
```

or

```
sqlite> UPDATE COMPANY SET ADDRESS = 'Texas' WHERE ID = 6;
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

you mentioned you only have 10 records. in that case it's better and also a lot simpler to use shared preferences instead of database. shared preferences can be used for key value kind of data which is exactly what you have, 10 keys with Boolean values. 

To learn more about shared preferences and also database update query you can watch videos from this youtube palylist. http://goo.gl/DAnQqr